# Minimize a function of $n$ variables for a given product

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I have $n$ variables denoted by $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n$ all of which take values in $(0,1)$.

I am trying to minimize $f(\vec{x})=1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-x_i)$  for a given $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i)=k $, where $k$ is a constant.

My intuition is that the point of minimum will have $x_i=x_j$ $\forall i,j \in \{1,2,\ldots n\}$. Can someone help me verify this mathematically.

Comment: I'd assume you have a solution where two values (say $x_1$ and $x_2$) are not equal, and then see if making them equal (to what?) can both remain feasible and improve your solution.  Try first with $n=2$ but then try a general $n>2$.

Comment: @TickaJules , with $n=2$, the problem is simply minimize $x+y$ for a given $xy$ which  happens when $x=y$. This is simple, but with larger values of $n$, there are pairwise products ,and higher order terms which seems difficult.

Comment: Let $M\equiv\prod_{i=3}^n (1-x_i)$ and $N\equiv\prod_{i=3}^n x_i$ and rewrite the statement ($M$ and  $N$ do not change when you play with $x_1$ and $x_2$).

Comment: @TickaJules I can see that essentially with $M$ and $N$ we are reducing this to a 2 variable problem where the minimum happens when $x_1=x_2.$ However, is this a rigorous  proof ?  Do you suggest  a sequence of steps involving eliminating a variable. It  starts like this: since $x_1=x_2=$ say $x$ , eliminate one variable and now repeat the same idea with $(x, x_3)$ and keep on eliminating.

Comment: Yes. For any two variables that take on different values, you can set them equal and repeat this until all variables have the same value.  Technically think of it as a proof by contradiction.  If someone gives you what they say is an optimal solution with two variables taking different values, then you can apply this technique, leading to a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I am also interested in seeing if someone can come up with 
 other elegant proofs. :)

Answer (score 1):

For $0 \lt k\lt 1$ we have

$$
L(x,\lambda) = -\prod_i(1-x_i)-\lambda\left(\prod_i x_i-k\right)
$$

and

$$
L_{x_j}= \frac{\prod_i(1-x_i)}{1-x_j}-\lambda\frac{\prod_i x_i}{x_j}=0
$$

as $\lambda$ is generic we can recast it as $\Lambda = \frac{\lambda}{\prod_i(1-x_i)}$ then the stationary conditions can be written as

$$
\frac{x_j}{1+x_j}-\Lambda k = 0
$$

then

$$
x_j = \frac{\Lambda k}{1-\Lambda k}
$$

after substitution into the restriction we have

$$
\left(\frac{\Lambda k}{1-\Lambda k}\right)^n = k
$$

and then

$$
\Lambda = \frac{1}{k+k^{1-\frac 1n}}
$$

hence

$$
x_j^* = k^{\frac 1n},\ \ \ \{j=1,\cdots,n\}
$$